# Why is my UILabel not displaying the correct value?

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift

I am running the following code:

```
var Pinned = "Your car is \(x.0) \(x.1) away"
println(Pinned)
self.distanceAway.text = String(Pinned)
```

x is a tuple of a double and a String, and the console is printing the correct value of pinned, but the text of the UILabel is not changing. This code is written inside of a NSBlockOperation which is being executed by a NSOperationQueue. I am not sure what I am overlooking, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: UIKit is not thread safe, so all UI changes should be performed from the main thread.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. What would be the most efficient way to bring this data back to the main thread?

Comment: See my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Execute code from the main thread in Swift:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    self.distanceAway.text = String(Pinned)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Execute code from the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
    //Your main thread code goes in here
    NSLog(@"Im on the main thread");       
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! (with some minor modifications to the language)